Excel - how to fix this countif formula
I have a trouble with the COUNTIF formula that I am using. I need to find a specific text in Row C with the value of Row A.
I need to find if any of the cells in row C contains the value of cell A2 which is p1234, however it returns "yes" even with the value of p12345678.

I tried removing the wildcard but it also doesn't work.




ColA
ColB
ColC




p1234
NO
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit p123456789


p5478
YES
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit p5478


p05384
YES
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit p05384




You are searching for a demarcated substring within a longer string. That being the case, you will need to also look for the delimiters. If the delimiters will always be a space and/or the substring will always be at the beginning/end of the string, this can be done with formulas. If you might have other delimiters (commas, hyphens, semicolons) then you might be better served with an implementation of Regular Expressions.

Try using the following formula with SEARCH() function to get the desired output:


=IF(SUM(1-ISERR(SEARCH(" "&A2&" "," "&C$2:C$4&" "))),"YES","NO")


If the search keys are case-sensitive, then can use FIND() in place of SEARCH()
=IF(SUM(1-ISERR(FIND(" "&A2&" "," "&C$2:C$4&" "))),"YES","NO")


• Using with ISNUMBER()+FIND()
=IF(SUM(N(ISNUMBER(FIND(" "&A2&" "," "&C$2:C$4&" ")))),"YES","NO")


• Or,
=IF(SUM(N(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(" "&A2&" "," "&C$2:C$4&" ")))),"YES","NO")


Or, Using BYROW()
=BYROW(A2:A4,LAMBDA(x,IF(OR(1-ISERR(FIND(" "&x&" "," "&C2:C4&" "))),"YES","NO")))


• One another way you can do it, using TEXTAFTER() provided the search key is always at the end of the strings to search:
=IF(OR(1-ISNA(TEXTAFTER(" "&C2:C4&" "," "&A2&" "))),"Yes","No")



How about vice versa? For example I'm gonna find if any of the words or text in the colC matches in colA. if any of the words in c2 is equal to a2:a4 then outputs yes or no. I hope my explanation is clear.

That is also possible. I will update. But I'm already in bed will it be okay if I update in the morning

No worries, it's okay. Thank you so much.

Can you also make it by 2 columns in different excel file?

I don't understand what you are trying to say. Does that make any sense at all?
